# CrystalReports data fields are all empty

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using VS community 2017 and sp25 of CrystalReports.

I made a program that is supposed to display data from a List object into a CrystalReport window. Here is the list class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AgricoveBilling
{
    public class reporter : IEnumerable<reporter>
    {
        public string InvoiceNo { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceDt { get; set; }
        public string DueDt { get; set; }
        public string BillToName { get; set; }
        public string BillToAdd { get; set; }

        public string ItemID1Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID1Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID1Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID1Total { get; set; }
        public string ItemID2Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID2Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID2Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID2Total { get; set; }
        public string ItemID3Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID3Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID3Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID3Total { get; set; }
        public string ItemID4Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID4Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID4Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID4Total { get; set; }
        public string ItemID5Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID5Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID5Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID5Total { get; set; }
        public string ItemID6Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID6Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID6Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID6Total { get; set; }
        public string ItemID7Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID7Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID7Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID7Total { get; set; }
        public string ItemID8Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID8Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID8Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID8Total { get; set; }
        public string ItemID9Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID9Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID9Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID9Total { get; set; }
        public string ItemID10Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID10Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID10Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID10Total { get; set; }
        public string ItemID11Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID11Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID11Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemID11Total { get; set; }

        public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
        public string DiscountType { get; set; }
        public decimal DiscountValue { get; set; }
        public decimal SubtotalLessDiscount { get; set; }
        public decimal TaxRate { get; set; }
        public decimal Totaltax { get; set; }
        public decimal GrossTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal Paid { get; set; }
        public decimal Due { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<reporter> GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I have set the reporter class as the datasource

The form where the CrystalReportViewer is embedded has the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

namespace AgricoveBilling
{
    public partial class Printpreview : Form
    {
        List<reporter> rep;
        public Printpreview(List<reporter> r)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            rep = r;      
        }

        private void Printpreview_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
            rpt.Load(@"..\printform.rpt");
            rpt.SetDataSource(rep);
            print_crystalreport.ReportSource = rpt;            
            print_crystalreport.Zoom(55);
            print_crystalreport.Refresh();

        }
    }
}
```

There are no errors. Using QuickWatch I have checked that all the C# objects are loading properly. I know that the correct rpt file is being loaded because the Text objects on the report are correct.

But there is absolutely no data on the report.

I'll be honest: I don't know how CrystalReports binds correct fields with the correct data. Was i supposed to write some code to do that somewhere?

I tried changing the iEnumerable to a regular class, but then during SetDataSoruce I am being told that the object is an invalid data source. I tried to use SetParamerterValue manually, but I am getting Badindex error that way. I made sure that the parameter name is correct.